# How to make the @keyframes animation work for IE and Firefox?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, firefox, css-animations

I am trying to make the css keyframes animation work in all browsers. So far, it has worked perfectly in Chrome and Safari. I used an alert to tell which browser is using and all pop up the alert box, except IE. In addition to that, firefox pops up the alert dialog, but does not execute the css animation. I specified -ms- for IE, -moz- for Firefox and -webkit- for Chrome and Safari. Firefox and IE just isn't working, I'm not sure where the problem is.

Secondly, I would like to know how to stop/pause a @keyframes animation during onmouseover the submitBtn and resume onmouseout. Thanks! [JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/6m7uN/4/)

**JavaScript Code:**

```
/*
 * Source: http://mrbool.com/how-to-detect-different-browsers-and-their-versions-using-javascript/25424#ixzz2v0Off3TV
 * Purpose: How to detect different browsers and their versions using JavaScript
 */

var objappVersion = navigator.appVersion;
var objAgent = navigator.userAgent;
var objbrowserName  = navigator.appName;
var objfullVersion  = '' + parseFloat(navigator.appVersion);
var objBrMajorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion,10);
var objOffsetName,objOffsetVersion,ix;

// create style element and produce animation
var cssAnimation = document.createElement('style');
//cssAnimation.type = 'text/css';
//cssAnimation.innerHTML = "@-webkit-keyframes pulse { 100% { background-color:green;color:black; } 50% {background-color:white;color:black;} 0% { background-color:green;color:black; } }";
document.head.appendChild(cssAnimation);
// cssAnimation.appendChild(rules);


var frm = document.getElementById("result");
var submitBtn = document.createElement("input");
submitBtn.type = "submit";
submitBtn.value = "Confirm Purchase";
frm.appendChild(submitBtn);
//submitBtn.style.webkitAnimation = "pulse 1s infinite";
// In Chrome
if((objOffsetVersion = objAgent.indexOf("Chrome")) != -1) 
{
    objbrowserName = "Chrome";
    objfullVersion = objAgent.substring(objOffsetVersion + 7);

    // add animation @-webkit-keyframes for Chrome
    cssAnimation.innerHTML = "@-webkit-keyframes pulse { 100% { background-color:green;color:white; } 50% {background-color:white;color:black;} 0% { background-color:green;color:white; } }";
    document.head.appendChild(cssAnimation);
    submitBtn.style.webkitAnimation = "pulse 1s infinite";
    alert("This is Chrome!");
}
// In Microsoft internet explorer
else if((objOffsetVersion = objAgent.indexOf("MSIE")) != -1) 
{
    objbrowserName = "Microsoft Internet Explorer";
    objfullVersion = objAgent.substring(objOffsetVersion + 5);
    // add animation @-ms-keyframes for IE
    cssAnimation.innerHTML = "@-ms-keyframes pulse { 100% { background-color:green;color:white; } 50% {background-color:white;color:black;} 0% { background-color:green;color:white; } }";
    document.head.appendChild(cssAnimation);
    submitBtn.style.msAnimation = "pulse 1s infinite";
    alert("This is IE!");
}
// In Firefox
else if((objOffsetVersion = objAgent.indexOf("Firefox")) !=- 1) 
{
    objbrowserName = "Firefox";

    // add animation @-moz-keyframes for Firefox
    cssAnimation.innerHTML = "@-moz-keyframes pulse { 100% { background-color:green;color:white; } 50% {background-color:white;color:black;} 0% { background-color:green;color:white; } }";
    document.head.appendChild(cssAnimation);
    submitBtn.style.mozAnimation = "pulse 1s infinite";
    alert("This is Firefox!");
}
// In Safari
else if((objOffsetVersion=objAgent.indexOf("Safari")) != -1) 
{
    objbrowserName = "Safari";
    objfullVersion = objAgent.substring(objOffsetVersion + 7);
    // add animation @-webkit-keyframes for Safari
    cssAnimation.innerHTML = "@-webkit-keyframes pulse { 100% { background-color:green;color:white; } 50% {background-color:white;color:black;} 0% { background-color:green;color:white; } }";
    document.head.appendChild(cssAnimation);
    submitBtn.style.webkitAnimation = "pulse 1s infinite";
    alert("This is Safari!");
}

submitBtn.onmouseover = function()
{
    submitBtn.style.transition = "ease-in-out all .4s";
    submitBtn.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    submitBtn.style.color = "green";
}
submitBtn.onmouseout = function()
{
    submitBtn.style.transition = "ease-in-out all .4s";
    submitBtn.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    submitBtn.style.color = "black";
}
```

Comment: Which version of IE are you testing on? One thing that is breaking it is a access denied issue in Jquery 1.0.1 (switching to edge fixes this). In IE11 the UA agent doesn't include MSIE to avoid getting legacy code, but I would still avoid doing UA detection if possible. http://jsfiddle.net/6m7uN/7/

Comment: IE has never needed the prefix and FF hasn't needed it since 3.6 so not including the official `@keyframe` & `animation` syntax is likely this issue.

Comment: @coldcoder At first glance I thought you put Gecko in there to be funny, but to my surprise it actually worked and didn't know IE's navigator was named that. Cool to know and thanks for the awesome help!

Comment: @Adrift Thanks for the tip! I shortened my code to only having cssAnimation for `@keyframes` and `@-webkit-keyframes` and it works on all major browsers.

Comment: Glad it worked out, we changed that as we support a lot of stuff that people wouldn't give us due to UA checking.